# JQuery Current Time Space Disppearing

Tags: jquery

this may be a stupid thing I am missing but how do I fix this?

I dont want the minutes to jump around like this.

I have this in my html:

```
<div id="myTime"></div>
```

This in my JavaScript:

```
var time = new Date();
var formatTime = '';
var tick = true;
setInterval('Tick()', 500);

    function Tick() {
        try {
            time = new Date();
            if (tick) {
                formatTime = time.getHours() + " : " + time.getMinutes();
                tick = false;
            } else {
                formatTime = (time.getHours() + "   " + time.getMinutes());
                tick = true;
            }
            $('#myTime').text(formatTime);
        } catch (ex) {
            $('#myTime').text('[Time Error]');
        }
    }
```

[here is a jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bebbie7/kf8eT/).

Comment: You could use css, spaces shouldn't be used as a way to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function Tick() {
    try {
        var time = new Date();
        $('#myTime').html(time.getHours() + '<span class="divider">' + (tick ? ':' : '') + '</span>' + time.getMinutes());
        tick = !tick;
    } catch (ex) {
        $('#myTime').text('[Time Error]');
    }
}
```

then

```
#myTime .divider {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vnYCj/)